# Empty %1 in RewriteCond using mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got some domains with same name but different TLDs - let's say `example.com` and `example.org`. I want to redirect all requests from [www.]example.com to www.example.org as to use only one main domain.

I've found following code I'm using in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)\.org$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       https://www.%1.org/$1 [L,R]
```

Problem is: it redirects to `https://www..org/`. Seems like variable `%1` is empty although it should contain the domain name ("example").

As I understand [Apache's httpd documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#InternalBackRefs) it should work like that.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+\.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.(?:.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1.org%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Empty %1 because in your case you use `!` for a negative test, Which does not correspond to...